# True live USB: Fully Functional

Tags: live-usb

I can't seem to have the affect I'm looking for on a "Live Ubuntu"

I want to run it from the USB drive, a fully functional, fully upgradable version.

I do not want to use as a "trial version", or to set up a dual boot or run in a virtual system.

I have kids that are killing my computer & everything on my HD, they need their own OS & drive but don't have the $$$ for a laptop for them, I just want it to work on the USB the same way it works on the C: drive

Answer (score 0):

The Live USB you create by following the [Ubuntu Installation Instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) is fully functional and will retain changes. However it will be too slow for practical purposes.

Note that if you put Ubuntu on your HD, then there is no need for the kids to have a separate machine or disc. As long as you don't make them Administrators, there is nothing they can mess up apart from their own home directories.

Answer (score 0):

A true (practical usable) ubuntu install cannot be made on a flash drive (well it can but it's quite difficult to do properly and fully functional)
You can however install ubuntu on an external hard drive (you can buy those for like 25 dollars because the capacity doesn't have to be that big).

First thing you do (optional but it might save you the trouble of having to fix your windows disk if you make a mistake) is disconnect your internal hard drive (it's not that hard, just take out the cable).

Next is just plain installing ubuntu on the external hard drive.

Reconnect your internal hard drive.

Change your boot setting so the usb has boot priority and you're done

Now I do have to note that unless you have usb 3.0 or e-sata it might run a little sluggish but not so much as to make it unusable. I've had some good results with a BM usb port in the past myself.